# Error callback being called when getting 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, canjs, canjs-model

I'm using Canjs on my app and when i call my function, the error callback is being called, but I'm getting a 200 response.

```
    var factory = new DTO(Factory);

    factory.save(
         function (data) {                                      
             self.element.html(can.view('viewDTO', {}));

         },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
        );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly: the returned response doesn't match the dataType specified (e.g. it expects a response that contains JSON but it isn't getting one); you're running up against the same origin policy when attempting to make a cross-domain AJAX request. What does the console say is wrong when you output `error`?

Comment: Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {